# Call a method from Adapter to Fragment and pass a variable with it Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

So what I want is on click of a button from my recycler view a method/function which is in my fragment should be called along with that it should send a variable too. I know I can use Listener or Interface but I have looked and implemented several solutions but none of them are working usually null pointer exception I don't know what mistake am doing so it would be helpful if someone will let me know how to do exactly by looking at my code I have removed some unnecessary part from my adapter too..

Adapter

```
public class AddPartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AddPartAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private  Context mContext;
private  List<User> mUsers;

EventListener listener;



public interface EventListener {
    void AddParticipant(String id);
}

public void addEventListener(EventListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}

public void removeEventListener(){
    listener = null;
}


public AddPartAdapter(Context mContext, List<User> mUsers) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mUsers = mUsers;

}



@NonNull
@Override
public AddPartAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.add_part_item, parent, false);
    return new AddPartAdapter.ViewHolder(viewGroup);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AddPartAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final User user = mUsers.get(position);

    holder.username.setText(user.getUsername());
    holder.dt.setText(user.getDt());

    if (user.getImageUrl().equals("default")) {
        holder.dp.setImageResource(R.drawable.user);
    } else {
        Glide.with(mContext).load(user.getImageUrl()).into(holder.dp);
    }

    holder.addpart_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String Variable = user.getId();//This is the variable that should pass
            //Send call that method and send the variablethat variable to Fragment
            listener.AddParticipant(Variable);
        }
    });

}
```

The Fragment

```
public class AddParticipantsFragment extends Fragment implements AddPartAdapter.EventListener {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<User> mUsers;

DatabaseReference databaseReference;
FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

private List<Chatlist>usersList;

private AddPartAdapter addPartAdapter;

public String groupId;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_participants, container, false);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    usersList = new ArrayList<>();
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            usersList.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){
                Chatlist chatlist = snapshot1.getValue(Chatlist.class);
                usersList.add(chatlist);
            }



            chatList();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    AddParticipants activity = (AddParticipants) getActivity();
    assert activity != null;
    groupId = activity.getMyData();
    return view;
}



private void chatList() {

    mUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            mUsers.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){
                User user = snapshot1.getValue(User.class);
                for (Chatlist chatlist : usersList){
                    assert user != null;
                    if(user.getId().equals(chatlist.getId())){
                        if(chatlist.getFriends().equals("Messaged")){
                            mUsers.add(user);

                        }if (chatlist.getFriends().equals("Requested")){
                            //DoNothing
                        }
                        if(chatlist.getFriends().equals("Blocked")){
                            //Dont do anything
                        }

                    }


                }

            }



            AddPartAdapter addPartAdapter = new AddPartAdapter(getContext(), mUsers);
            addPartAdapter.addEventListener();//Here inside the bracket what to add.
            recyclerView.setAdapter(addPartAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}




public void AddParticipant(String id) {
    //And it should initialize this method
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Grouplist").child(groupId);
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap1 = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap1.put("id", id);
    hashMap1.put("admin","false");
    databaseReference.setValue(hashMap1);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    addPartAdapter.removeEventListener();
}
}
```

And Heres the logcat

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.margsapp.messenger.Adapter.AddPartAdapter$EventListener.AddParticipant(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at com.margsapp.messenger.Adapter.AddPartAdapter$1.onClick(AddPartAdapter.java:70)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

Comment: Can you add your listener impl code? Also NPE error log

Comment: Yeah sure I will edit the question.

Comment: I have added the listener and the log can you please check and tell wheres the problem?

Comment: yes, it will crash with NPE. You are creating 2 instances of Adapter. In 1 instance you are passing listener and in 1 instance, you are passing context & userlist data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way,

In your adapter class, create 2 method. Add & remove listener.

```
public addEventListener(EventListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}

public removeEventListener(){
   listener = null;
}
```

Fragment class

```
public class AddParticipantsFragment extends Fragment implements AddPartAdapter.EventListener  {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<User> mUsers;

DatabaseReference databaseReference;
FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

private List<Chatlist>usersList;


public String groupId;
private AddPartAdapter addPartAdapter



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_participants, container, false);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    usersList = new ArrayList<>();

    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            usersList.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){
                Chatlist chatlist = snapshot1.getValue(Chatlist.class);
                usersList.add(chatlist);
            }

            chatList();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    AddParticipants activity = (AddParticipants) getActivity();
    assert activity != null;
    groupId = activity.getMyData();


    return view;
}



private void chatList() {

    mUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            mUsers.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){
                User user = snapshot1.getValue(User.class);
                for (Chatlist chatlist : usersList){
                    assert user != null;
                    if(user.getId().equals(chatlist.getId())){
                        if(chatlist.getFriends().equals("Messaged")){
                            mUsers.add(user);

                        }if (chatlist.getFriends().equals("Requested")){
                            //DoNothing
                        }
                        if(chatlist.getFriends().equals("Blocked")){
                            //Dont do anything
                        }

                    }


                }

            }



            addPartAdapter = new AddPartAdapter(getContext(), mUsers);
            adapter.addEventListener(this)
            recyclerView.setAdapter(addPartAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}



 //This is the method that should be called and id is the variable I want
 public void AddParticipant(String id) {
    //And it should initialize this method
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Grouplist").child(groupId);
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap1 = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap1.put("id", id);
    hashMap1.put("admin","false");
    databaseReference.setValue(hashMap1);
 }


 override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        adapter.removeEventListener()
    }
```

}

Comment: I have added what you said to add so I added it but I don't know what to add inside the bracket in fragment and at the same time please check whether I added as it should be.

Comment: addPartAdapter = new AddPartAdapter(getContext(), mUsers);
addPartAdapter.addEventListener(AddParticipantsFragment.this);